# Getting wrong data from SQL view when putting it into a C# list

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a SQL view that I want to use and put it into a C# list into an ASP.NET MVC project so that I can execute a query on that list. The problem is that I get wrong data from the view.

When I try to get all the data from the SQL view, the count is correct but some rows are shown multiple times and some are simply gone. Same thing happens when I try go execute some logic on the data from that view.

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("Home/Testing/{godina}/{istorija}/{decursus_id}/{therapy_id}")]
public ActionResult Testing(string godina, string istorija, int decursus_id, string therapy_id)
{
    List<v_as_stac_terapija_komercijalni> terapijaKomercijalniList = db.v_as_stac_terapija_komercijalni
        .Where(x => x.godina == godina
                    && x.istorija == istorija
                    && x.decursus_id == decursus_id
                    && x.therapy_id == therapy_id)
        .ToList();

    return View();
}
```

So according to the data in my SQL view and according to the parameters given in this action, the list should hold 3 results, and the count is 3 but the problem is I always get the first record that matches this parameters 3 times, instead of getting the real 3 records.

I can provide additional information if necessary. Thanks

Comment: Probably your entity has wrong PrimaryKey.

Comment: First of all: what RDBMS is this for? Please add a relevant tag!

Comment: Second: using EF (which I believe you are) against a view from a RDBMS can be tricky. Does your view include the **primary keys** of all tables that are used in creating the result set of the view? If not - you might get *false readings* from EF when reading the data.

Comment: I use Microsoft SQL Server 2012. Since its a sql View and it holds data from 5 different tables it doesn't have a primary key it self, so is the problem in the primary keys in one of the tables from which this view was generated?

Comment: Try `AsNoTracking` or define your entity as `HasNoKey`.

Comment: There's almost no information here. EF Core like all ORMs deals with Objects, it's not a replacement for SQL. It Maps Objects to Relational constructs like tables and views, it doesn't expose the tables to the application. EF Core will try to guess primary keys, types and relations based on conventions but it can't guess everything.

Comment: If you only want to map query results to objects us Dapper and just map the results. EF Core has to do a lot more to map objects so it can track changes and persist them

Answer (score 1):

You've not really told us much about what RDBMS you're using, nor do we know what the view looks like and what underlying tables it might query to get its result set.

From my own personal experience, I know using data from views in EF can be a bit tricky. Possibly, the trouble just simply is the lack of an explicit primary key. Every table in your database ought to have a proper, well defined primary key.

What happens here is: since there's no primary key, EF will just use *all non-nullable columns* from the view as a "replacement" PK.

And when EF reads the data, it will go:

- read the row
- check the primary key (or the "stand-in" PK in this case)
- if it has *already read* a row with that PK - it just duplicates that row that it already has - it will **disregard** any non-PK columns from the view!

So in your case, once it has read a first row with the "stand-in" PK, any further rows with those values will just get the already read values - no matter what's stored in the database!

**SOLUTION:** as I said before: every table ought to have a proper primary key to uniquely identify each individual row - and in your view definition, you should include *all* primary key columns from all tables involved in defining your view into the result set of that view. With this, EF will hopefully automagically pick the *right columns* as its "ad-hoc" primary key and will actually read the values as returned from the RDBMS in your view.